# Numpy Conditional Max of Range

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I'm trying to make a version of my program faster using as much Pandas and Numpy as possible.  I am new to Numpy but have been grasping most of it, but I am having trouble with conditional formatting a column with the max of a range. This is the code I am trying to use to achieve this:

```
x=3
df1['Max']=numpy.where(df1.index>=x,max(df1.High[-x:],0))
```

Basically, I am trying to conditionally put the maximum value over the last 3 entries into a cell and repeat down the column.  Any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: Please include some data that you are working with.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`Scipy's maximum_filter`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.filters.maximum_filter1d.html) -

```
from scipy.ndimage.filters import maximum_filter1d

df['max'] = maximum_filter1d(df.High,size=3,origin=1,mode='nearest')
```

Basically, maximum_filter operates in a sliding window looking for maximum in that window. Now, by default each such `max` computation would be performed with window being centered at the index itself. Since, we are looking to go three elements before and ending at the current one, we need to change that *centeredness* with the parameter `origin`. Therefore, we have it set at `1`.

Sample run -

```
In [21]: df
Out[21]: 
   High  max
0    13   13
1    77   77
2    16   77
3    30   77
4    25   30
5    98   98
6    79   98
7    58   98
8    51   79
9    23   58
```

**Runtime test**

Got me interested to see how this Scipy's sliding max operation performs against Pandas's rolling max method on performance. Here's some results on big datasizes -

```
In [55]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,99,(10000)),columns=['High'])

In [56]: %%timeit  # @Merlin's rolling based solution :
    ...: df['max'] = df.High.rolling(window=3, min_periods=1).max()
    ...: 
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.35 ms per loop

In [57]: %%timeit  # Using Scipy's max filter :
    ...: df['max1'] = maximum_filter1d(df.High,size=3,\
    ...: origin=1,mode='nearest')
    ...: 
1000 loops, best of 3: 487 µs per loop
```

Comment: thanks for `maximum_filter1d` - i didn't know this function!

Comment: thank you very much! it is a very valuable function to have in the repertoire. greatly improved the performance!

Answer (score 3):

Here is the logic on `np.where`

```
 numpy.where('test something,if true ,if false)
```

I think you need below.

```
dd= {'to': [100, 200, 300, 400, -500, 600, 700,800, 900, 1000]}

df = pd.DataFrame(dd)
df

         to
0   100
1   200
2   300
3   400
4  -500
5   600
6   700
7   800
8   900
9  1000

df['Max'] =  df.rolling(window=3, min_periods=1).max()


   to     Max
0   100   100.0
1   200   200.0
2   300   300.0
3   400   400.0
4  -500   400.0
5   600   600.0
6   700   700.0
7   800   800.0
8   900   900.0
9  1000  1000.0
```

Comment: Merlin, your solution works quite good as well. By using the shift function I was able to use it in other parts of my program to speed it up. 

df['Max'] = df.to.shift().rolling(window=3, min_periods=1).max()

This changed the max column to show the max of the 3 previous entries to line up with the 4th entry.

Thank you for the insight!